# Can't get embedded driver from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

I'm trying to run application working with derby database. I've installed derby. Added jars to classpath and to build path of eclipse. I'm working with [this guide](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html). When I run sample app it starts and finishes successfully. But when I use in my program:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
```

It says:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
```

Though it works fine at sample. I'm stuck. Need help.
my classpath:

`/opt/Apache/db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin/lib/derby.jar:/opt/Apache/db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin/lib/derbytools.jar`:
[image: my build path]
Full stack trace

```
11.02.2014 11:54:20 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
11.02.2014 11:54:20 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Java_lab1' did not find a matching property.
11.02.2014 11:54:20 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Java_lab2' did not find a matching property.
11.02.2014 11:54:20 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Lab4DWP' did not find a matching property.
11.02.2014 11:54:20 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
11.02.2014 11:54:20 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
11.02.2014 11:54:20 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 559 ms
11.02.2014 11:54:20 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
11.02.2014 11:54:20 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
11.02.2014 11:54:21 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/docs
11.02.2014 11:54:21 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/examples
11.02.2014 11:54:21 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
11.02.2014 11:54:21 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
11.02.2014 11:54:21 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@63fb050c')
11.02.2014 11:54:21 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/host-manager
11.02.2014 11:54:21 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/manager
11.02.2014 11:54:21 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT
11.02.2014 11:54:21 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
11.02.2014 11:54:21 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
11.02.2014 11:54:21 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 628 ms
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at DB.DBServlet.doGet(DBServlet.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
11.02.2014 11:54:32 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Lab4DWP] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.main_jsp._jspService(main_jsp.java:80)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: did you add derby.jar? The tutorial cleary says,if you see this error, what should be followed. Did you try that? Because the error says you dont have the jar in your classpath.

Comment: Here are my classpath and build path

Comment: it should be fine then. In any of your class, try importing it for test purpose, like `import org.apache.derby.jdbc.` press control+space . Is Eclipse showing you the various classes in the package? Also do you see derby.jar inside the Libraries in Java Resources in your eclipse project?

Comment: Yep, it shows. Moreover I chose embedded driver. The mistake is the same.

Comment: can you show me the full stacktrace? i think i have to try it out to see if i get the same error. There are many questions in StackOverflow already regarding this. you can try your luck referring them meanwhile

Comment: Here is full stack trace

Comment: Manually Copy paste that jar file(derby.jar) into lib folder...and try..

Comment: Lib folder of derby? It is there.

Comment: No man...Lab4DWP is a WebApp right ?? In that WebContent/WEB-INF/lib ...in this Lib copy paste

Comment: Yep, there isn't this mistake any more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lab4DWP's WebContent/WEB-INF/lib copy paste all the Derby jars and try